# Draft & Fire Stop at Soffit

Tags: fire, draft, blocking

I am unclear whether the area between each floor joist needs fire blocking. Is it best practice to block the area between each floor joist where the soffit intersects or is draft stopping at the required interval acceptable?

My AHJ has a detail that has lots of options on it which I have done one of the three options but smoke and flame could still run through the soffit and up in the floor joist above the adjacent room[image]...

[image]